# Test.loadData() - undocumented (but useful) behavior loading relationships

Tags: apex, unit-test

**Premise**

I want to load Accounts and their related Contacts using `Test.loadData()` and `StaticResources`. How do I do this given that the Contact records must have the ID of their parent Account yet the CSV file containing the Contacts can't know in advance what the Account's ID will be?

[SFDC Help KB has one solution using Cases and CaseComment](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181909&language=en_US) and there is [an Idea here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxHhAAI).

The SFDC KB article uses legitimate ID values (18 chars) in the parent CSV's ID column and child CSV's parentId column. The child CSV parentId column must reference the same ID as used for its intended parent.

But clearly the parentId in the CSV won't be the real ID of the inserted parent SObject. So, can the ID values be arbitrary as long as they are unique?

Comment: I was always annoyed that Test.loadData performed the insert and didn't hand back an in-memory data set (so that I might set up the relationships prior to DML) - now we know why! Thank you! Profound insight and profound question!

Comment: Probably should be in Q&A format, but I approve this content.

Comment: yes, i thought of that and can convert to Q&A once I feel the assertion in the question does not turn out to have a community-discovered flaw

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> Moving question into answer

And the answer appears to be yes (a tip to a colleague of mine who discovered this) and it works for master-detail relationships too

**The Proof**

- `Account`
- `Contact` with lookup relationship AccountId and custom lookup `Alternate_Account__c`

Here's the CSV file for the Account - note the values of `0` and `1` for the test `Account.ID` rows:
[image]

And here's the CSV for the Contacts - note the values in the `AccountId` column and `Alternate_Account__c` column reference the artificial IDs of Account CSV rows:

[image]

Using this Apex testmethod, I loaded the Accounts data from the static resource first and then the Contacts data from its static resource. I displayed the constructed SObject relationships using System.debug:

```
@isTest
private class TestStaticResourceDataLoad {
    private static void testStaticResourceDataLoadMasterDetail() {
        List<SObject> aList = Test.loadData(Account.sObjectType,'testAccounts');
        List<SObject> cList = Test.loadData(Contact.sObjectType,'testContacts');

        String res = '';
        for (Account a: [select id, name, (select id, firstname, lastName,email, 
                                 reportsTo.lastname, alternate_account__r.name from Contacts) 
                             from Account where id IN :aList]) {
            String cRes = '';
            for (Contact c: a.contacts)
                cRes += '\n...name= ' + c.firstName + ' ' + c.lastName + ' ' + c.email + 
                             ' altAcct=' + c.alternate_account__r.name;
            res += '\n account id/name: ' + a.id + ' ' + a.name + ' w/ contacts: ' + cRes;
        }
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'res='+res);
    }
}
```

And here are the results:

```
13:11:43.657 (3657616477)|USER_DEBUG|[15]|INFO|res=
 account id/name: 001m0000007pN6hAAE 00AccountName w/ contacts: 
   name= 0.0fname 0.0lname 0.0lname@fubar.com altAcct=01AccountName
   name= 0.1fname 0.1lname 0.1lname@fubar.com altAcct=01AccountName
 account id/name: 001m0000007pN6iAAE 01AccountName w/ contacts: 
   name= 1.0fname 1.0lname 1.0lname@fubar.com altAcct=00AccountName
```

The Contacts are appropriately parented and the `Contact.alternate_account__c` lookup is  also accurate.

**Side note** - what does not work is references within a StaticResource dataset. For example, I tried to use the Contact.ReportsToId field to have one Contact be a child of another in the same batch as shown here:

[image]

This isn't surprising as the Sobjects are inserted as a batch and the intra-Sobject reference is not resolvable yet. No different than using DataLoader.

**Side note 2**
Another use case I couldn't get to work via this approach was loading PricebookEntry rows for the standard pricebook unless you used the actual ID of the standard `Pricebook` as you can't insert a standard pricebook via testmethods.  This can have some portability issues

**Summary**

What is striking to me is that across Apex statement executions (the successive Test.loadData(..) lines), SFDC keeps track of a mapping between real IDs of the loaded Sobject and the fake ID you specify in the CSV file so you can build relationships. None of this is documented in the [Apex Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_testing_load_data.htm) and the casual developer could easily assume that Test.loadData(..) can only load top level SObjects or otherwise force the developer to post-process and add the relationships later.

Comment: side note 4 - it is allowed to use same Id for different object records, meaning both `account` record and `contact` record can use `1` in `Id` field.

Comment: side note 3 - load two datasets for same object will result in "Validation Errors While Saving Record"

Comment: Personally, I feel they should support import of data with relationships in much the same way from uploaded CSV files or uploaded CSV file bundles (ZIPs) - by uploaded I mean uploaded at the time of data import, rather than as a static resource.

Comment: @XiXiao I just tried loading two datasets for the same custom object and that works these days. I also included a self lookup relationship in these two files and it was populated correctly. (I couldn't get the lookup to work when using only one file.)

Comment: Side note 5 - the fake IDs need not be integers; any string seems to work.  This allows you to use existing Ids from an org export, or alternate values like product codes.

Answer (score 2):

For the Side Note: Its is valid. There is no way to populate self lookups. But that can be feasible if SFDC can start supporting batch number as parameter to this method Test.loadData ( even in that case first record will be left out )

It is a good observation to see that ID field can be manipulated and relationship between the parent and child can be maintained. I think Salesforce should update this behavior as it is a key feature to use the full capability of Test.loadData method. Missing in documentation has resuilted in this post for Fake Fields https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000167032&language=en_US
Actually if documentation is added for this then workaround of the above post is not needed.

You can check this and see if it deserves to vote this idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxHhAAI

Thanks
Amit

Comment: I believe for self-lookups we could use external id fields

Comment: I just tried loading two datasets for the same custom object and that works these days. I also included a self lookup relationship in these two files and it was populated correctly. (I couldn't get the lookup to work when using only one file.)