# How to create test objects with lastModifiedDate in past

Tags: apex, unit-test

So I created a Job that is supposed to run every day and give me a list of `Opportunity` records that have not been modified in the last 6 months, so I can email the owner and let him/her know that the status of that record will change to Closed Lost. When I'm writing the test class for this I'm running into an issue. I can not set the LastModifiedDate to 180 days ago. I've read and I was told that I can use Dependency Injection to put any date I want but I don't know how to do that, has anyone done it before? Do you have a sample code I could use?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: are you using Json.deserialize to create your mock data or test.loadData ?

Comment: No, I'm just using permission set to overwrite audit fields but it still won't work.

Comment: @crop1645 I'm using  Json.deserialize to create my mock data, I just can't insert it, I know I need to change my job now and check if I'm passing a list of Opps or not and create it if it's not there. Right?

Comment: JSON.deserialize creates SObjects, not persisted SObjects; I'm not sure if via Apex `Database.insert` you can insert audit fields as the doc states it applies only to the API - and the API is not available in testmethods.  I'm not sure I understand your question -- to test a batchable class invoked by `Database.execute()` that uses a start() queryLocator, you need to mock persistent data ..otherwise, you can test just the execute() method with sobjects created by JSON.deserialize (but this doesn;t test the start() method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to create testdata with `lastModifiedDate` in the past is through `Test.loadData()`

**Step 1- Create CSV File for your sobject**

```
name    createdDate            lastmodifiedDate
00foo   2000-01-01T00:00:00Z    2001-01-01T00:00:00Z
01foo   2000-01-02T00:00:00Z    2001-01-02T00:00:00Z
```

**Step 2 - save as Static Resource** (named here as `sfseLastModDateInPast`)

**Step 3 - Code test method**

```
@istest
private static void testLastModDateInPast () {

    Foo__c[] fList = test.loadData(Foo__c.sObjectType,'sfseLastModDateInPast');
    system.debug(loggingLevel.INFO,fList);
}
```

**Notes**

If your object has triggers then you'll want to disable before executing Test.loadData as otherwise the triggers may cause lastModifiedDate to be refreshed to `now`

If you need to create relationships in the static resource, use external IDs [or see undocumented tip here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/54527/2602)

Debug output (truncated)

```
  10:34:13:261 USER_DEBUG [7]|INFO|(Foo__c:{
     Id=a1pJ0000003ocTAIAY, 
     Name=00foo, 
     CreatedDate=2000-01-01 00:00:00,  // in past
     LastModifiedDate=2001-01-01 00:00:00, // in past
     SystemModstamp=2016-01-02 18:34:09, ... )
```

Answer (score 5):

I would just manipulate your `QueryLocator`.

```
public class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>
{
    @TestVisible static String whereClause = 'WHERE LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_MONTHS:6';
    static final String soql = 'SELECT Id FROM Opportunity ' + whereClause;
    // other logic
}
```

Then in your test just change the clause to an empty string or whatever you like.