# Schedulable Apex - Test Class

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I have created a schedulable apex that gets the leads that have been last modified for more than 3 days and perform an operation. But for my test class, i want to insert some test data... But the test data will have lastmodified date always today. So the query when i run the test class will not return results. How could i implement a solution to insert those test data and make the last modified date more than 3 so that query includes those records and pass the test ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways.

- Quick and dirty: do an `if` on the query and return today's records if `is running test`, return `3 days ago` otherwise. (Be careful with timezone differences, and tests running at around mid-night)
- Using [Test.loadData()](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332070&type=1&mode=1)
- Using [JSON.deserialize()](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332070&type=1&mode=1)

some more guided steps are given on this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103829/how-to-create-test-objects-with-lastmodifieddate-in-past)

I personally like option 2, as it allows you to easily maintain Test data and be able to have a quick look at it, but I understand that playing with recordTypes might be a challenge.

Comment: Thank you very much Sergio:)