# Using Test.loadData() for many level self-relationship data

Tags: unit-test, data, csv

I use loadData method very often in my test methods for custom settings and objects where lookup fields are not necessary for my case. Now, I ran into a situation where I need to create hundreds of test records. They are all configuration records. The object has self relationship and it is 4 level deep.

Ex: An Account has 3 child accounts and each child has 4 grand-child accounts and each grand child has 10 children. In total they are in hundreds. The sad part is, I need all of them for my test cases.

I don't want to use seeAllData = true and wondering if I can build relationships with in CSV (Single or multiple) and use it in my test method. Or is there any other better way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Check this...http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54527/test-loaddata-undocumented-behavior

Comment: According to that thread, references with in static resource data set are not possible. I may end up creating 4,5 static resources.

Comment: I think, creating multiple static resource for each level is only way to use Test.loadTest()

Comment: try using external ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating 4 static resources. One for each level in relationship.

I gave Ids 0,1,2,3... for the top level.

[image: Top Level]

00,01,02... for the second level

[image: Level Two]

000,001,002... for the third level.

[image: Level Three]

No ids for the bottom level as it doesn't need to be referenced anywhere.
[image]

It worked perfectly fine. I basically implemented [Answer from this thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54527/test-loaddata-undocumented-behavior) for multi level self relationships.

Comment: This is great Avinash N -- I wasn't aware the simulated IDs would work across multiple Test.loadData() calls. Nice work