# Using Test.loadData with required lookup fields

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have an object with a required lookup field. I want to use [`Test.loadData()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm) to load hundreds of records from a CSV for unit testing for this object, but I want the unit test to be portable, meaning I can't hardcode the lookup Id.

This seems like an extremely common scenario, but I've had little luck finding any solutions to this scenario. Do I have to generate different CSV files for different orgs, or is there something obvious I'm missing?

As an example, how could I load User records from a CSV, given that `ProfileId` is a required field?

Comment: is this a managed package use case? or a multi-sandbox within one PROD org use case?

Comment: @cropredy - I have many potential use cases, including a managed package and a multi-sandbox org.

Comment: Well, with pre-existing Profiles, in a multi-sandbox org, the ProfileIds will all be the same in each sandbox

Comment: Thanks. Another example may have been better... I was asking in the general case.

Comment: the undocumented load behavior works well for many use cases, but won't on references to data not being loaded (i.e. ProfileId) -- sorry to focus on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no such support in Test.loadData() to handle complex lookups and Master detail.

But there is one idea on idea exchange that you can vote for.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxHhAAI

Meanwhile a workaround will be create a replica of Test.loadData() in APEX.
ie read from static resource in your test class and provide logic to replicate the records via your normal DML statements. I know its tedious and ugly. But when facing huge data crises during tests,this was the approach we finalized.

There is Also an **Undocumented behavior of test.loadData** that you can use to populate relationships. Yes it works miraculously but we don't know when salesforce will stop supporting it.

[Test.loadData() - undocumented (but useful) behavior loading relationships](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54527/test-loaddata-undocumented-but-useful-behavior-loading-relationships)

Comment: Elaborate how this helps specific example of OP - loading User records with lookup to Profile across many orgs

Comment: @cropredy - User was one example I ran into, but it's not the only case where I have a required field. I think this answer sums things up for me. It confirms my suspicions, at least.