# Test.loadData() is there a way to load sObects with lookups to itself?

Tags: unit-test, data-loader, csv, data-import

We have some custom object that has lookups to itself. Those objects used for some configs and there are quite a lot of them. Would be nice to create and load them from static resource for tests as well as import to another orgs.

I tried to use this approach [Test.loadData() - undocumented (but useful) behavior loading relationships](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54527/test-loaddata-undocumented-but-useful-behavior-loading-relationships?noredirect=1&lq=1) but looks like it's not possible to insert objects with lookups to itself.

That topic is quite outdated maybe there is some new solution?

Comment: You can specify ids, right? Just load the parents first, then the children?

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson! This approach works in test classes. Will try External ID for data loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the Id values, then load the parent record(s) first, followed by any child records. A simple example would be to use the `Account` object and its `ParentId` field.

Static Resource 1:

```
Id                 ParentId
001000000000000
```

Static Resource 2:

```
Id                 ParentId
001000000000001    001000000000000
001000000000002    001000000000000
001000000000003    001000000000000
```