# How to load Opportunity Product using Test.loadData?

Tags: unit-test, static-resources, pricebook

Is it doable for Opportunity Product to be load using Test.loadData while Standard Price is not accessible in Test class?

I try to automate the data population make it easy for user to define scenario using in csv files (static resource)  .I'm able to find answer how to map the relationship on Account,Opportunity,Contact in csv but I 'm not able to find solution for Opportunity Product.One of the reason is how we going to define Price book Entry in Test Class for this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Test.getStandardPricebookId()` to get StandardPriceBookId in Test Class.

```
//create Account
Account acct = new Account(Name='test',......);
insert acct;

Opportunity oppty = new Opportunity(Name='TestOppty', AccountId=acct.Id,....);
insert oppty;

Product2 elderProd = new Product2(
        IsActive = true,
        Name = 'Elder Gifts'
        );
insert elderProd;

ID standardPBID = Test.getStandardPricebookId(); 

PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(
        Pricebook2Id = standardPBID,
        Product2Id = prod.Id,
        UnitPrice = 10000,
        IsActive = true
        );
    insert standardPrice;

List<Pricebook2> standardPB = [select id from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true];

OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(
    OpportunityId = oppty.Id,
    Quantity = 5,
    PricebookEntryId = standardPrice.Id,
    UnitPrice = 1);
insert oli;

//following code for Custom pricebook

Pricebook2 customPB = new Pricebook2(
    Name='Custom Pricebook',
    isActive=true
    );
insert customPB;


PricebookEntry elderPBE = new PricebookEntry(
    Pricebook2Id = customPB.Id,
    Product2Id = elderProd.Id,
    UnitPrice = 0,
    IsActive = true
    );
insert elderPBE;
```

**Update**

You have to use actual id of Standard Pricebook as you can't insert a standard pricebook via testmethods. Refer this [Test.loadData() - undocumented (but useful) behavior loading relationships](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54527/test-loaddata-undocumented-but-useful-behavior-loading-relationships)

Comment: I am looking a way to populate  Opportunity Product data from Test.loadData (Static Resource-csv ) not code it in apex class. Is it possible?My bad, maybe my question is not clear enough. Updated it.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: This issue will it solve if I just @seealldata=true ?

Comment: @unidha - avoid seeAllData like the plague for this use case. Std pricebookId is the same across sandboxes and PROD so Santanu's suggestion at bottom of answer is the way to go using Test.LoadData