# Create Opportunity & related OpportunityHistory Test Data

Tags: unit-test, batch, opportunity, opportunity-history, test.loaddata

I've written a batch job which queries a bunch of Opportunity records and their related OpportunityHistory records to capture data from the history records on the Opportunity.  This is working as expected.

My issue is writing unit tests without using `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)`.  Sure it makes things easier, but I would prefer to be meticulous with my testing.

I found that I couldn't create anything to do with OpportunityHistory records, even without DML.  I then remember coming across the `Test.loadData()` method while going through [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm) one day, then I came across this very useful post: [Test.loadData() - undocumented (but useful) behavior loading relationships](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54527/test-loaddata-undocumented-but-useful-behavior-loading-relationships).

I started out simple and used the following two CSV data files:

opportunities.csv

```
Name, Amount, Id, CloseDate, CurrencyIsoCode, Type, LeadSource, StageName
Test Opp, 1000, 11, 2022-11-15, EUR, Device, Marketing, Awareness
```

opportunityhistory.csv

```
Id, OpportunityId, StageName, CreatedDate
21, 11, Awareness, 2022-11-15T08:01:04Z
```

The Opportunity data loads in without issue.  For the OpportunityHistory data I was originally having problems with the CreatedDate DateTime format being wrong due to a silly typo I had in the date.  Once that was corrected I started getting a *super helpful* Salesforce error:

`System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error: 214752186-150435 (-284133470) (-284133470)`

I managed to reproduce this in two different orgs.  One my own personal Dev org, and one being an unrelated sandbox.

---

Has anyone managed to find a nice way around creating OpportunityHistory records in a unit test using either `Test.loadData()` or other methods?